# how to use logger if the function is used in different modules?

Tags: python, logging

I have a function

```
def is_data_up_to_date() 
    logger('checking data in the database')
    ... check data ...
    logger('last date is {}'.format(last_date))
```

which is used in multiple cases, and the logger there is a module wised global variable. My questions are:

1. Is it a good practice to the put logger inside the function like this? If not what are the alternative ways? Sometimes I need to log some specific values so it is easy for me to put logger inside the function so that I do not need to return that value out of the function.
2. Is it OK to pass the logger as an instance to the method so that different module can share the logger object ... is there a better way (or maybe a standard way) of doing this?

Comment: Do you know about the [`logging module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) that comes with python? This does not answer any of your questions, I'm just making sure you are not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @RedX I have read it a bit and just be able to make it work in the simplest case. Definitely will read more there.